# How to make an 'episode' variable in R (running a 'for loop' in every group?)

Tags: r, for-loop, survival-analysis

This might be a really simple problem, but I can't figure out how to do it. I'm doing a survival analysis for recurrent events, and I need to create an 'episode' variable. For each id (in my data, 'country'), 'episode' starts at 1 for every country and increases by 1 after each 'event' occurred (I just typed 'episode' manually in the below excerpt'). The 'episode' variable resets to 1 for every country.

If the 'episode' variable did not reset for every country, I would just use a for loop over the entire dataset.

```
Country     Year    Event   Episode
Cameroon    1960    0   1
Cameroon    1961    0   1
Cameroon    1962    1   1
Cameroon    1963    0   2
Cameroon    1964    0   2
Cameroon    1965    0   2
Cameroon    1966    0   2
Cameroon    1967    0   2
Cameroon    1968    0   2
Cameroon    1969    0   2
Cameroon    1970    0   2
Cameroon    1971    0   2
Cameron         1972    0   2
Chad            1960    0   1
Chad            1961    0   1
Chad            1962    0   1
Chad            1963    0   1
Chad            1964    0   1
Chad            1965    0   1
Chad            1966    0   1
Chad            1967    1   1
Chad            1968    0   2
Chad            1969    0   2
Chad            1970    0   2
Chad            1971    1   2
Chad            1972    0   3
```

[image]

Thanks much

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `cumsum` on a grouped dataframe. Note that I fixed the typo where one row was called `Cameron`. We also need to use `lag` to account for the fact that you want the `Episode` to change only on the next row.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- structure(list(Country = c("Cameroon", "Cameroon", "Cameroon", "Cameroon", "Cameroon", "Cameroon", "Cameroon", "Cameroon", "Cameroon", "Cameroon", "Cameroon", "Cameroon", "Cameron", "Chad", "Chad", "Chad", "Chad", "Chad", "Chad", "Chad", "Chad", "Chad", "Chad", "Chad", "Chad", "Chad"), Year = c(1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972), Event = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), Episode = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -26L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Country = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), Year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Event = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Episode = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
tbl %>%
  mutate(Country = if_else(Country == "Cameron", "Cameroon", Country)) %>%
  arrange(Country, Year) %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(Ep = cumsum(lag(Event, default = 0) == 1) + 1)
#> # A tibble: 26 x 5
#> # Groups:   Country [2]
#>    Country   Year Event Episode    Ep
#>    <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 Cameroon  1960     0       1     1
#>  2 Cameroon  1961     0       1     1
#>  3 Cameroon  1962     1       1     1
#>  4 Cameroon  1963     0       2     2
#>  5 Cameroon  1964     0       2     2
#>  6 Cameroon  1965     0       2     2
#>  7 Cameroon  1966     0       2     2
#>  8 Cameroon  1967     0       2     2
#>  9 Cameroon  1968     0       2     2
#> 10 Cameroon  1969     0       2     2
#> # … with 16 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, I see how it is supposed to work. However, for some weird reason, I cannot seem to get the mutate function to work. When I type dat$episode (did it with 'episode' rather than 'Ep' as you did in the example), it just gives me "Unknown or uninitialised column: 'episode'. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: I took care of it by just executing the command repeatedly in R studio until it stopped giving me weird warnings - I just don't know why it happened, but from a cursory online search, some other people seem to have the same problem with the tidyverse package.

Comment: `Ep` is the name of the new column, you just type `episode` and not `dat$episode`. You can use the same logic without mutate if you want.